# How can I publish to a Gazebo Topic from Python

Tags: python, gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to build a publisher in python, for now I am using the 'Topic visualization' tool in gzclient as my subscriber.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1616/how-can-i-publish-to-a-gazebo-topic-from-python/) by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That took a while to figure out, but this works on Gazebo 1.4.

Note that I copied all of the necessary message .proto files from the gazebo source directory into a directory './proto/msg' and compiled them with:

```
protoc -I='./proto/msg' --python_out='./proto' ./proto/msg/*.proto
```

I then made that directory a python library with

```
touch ./proto/__init__.py
```

Finally I used this script to publish some bogus data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import time
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from proto.packet_pb2     import Packet
from proto.publish_pb2    import Publish
from proto.request_pb2    import Request
from proto.response_pb2   import Response
from proto.pose_pb2       import Pose
from proto.subscribe_pb2  import Subscribe

MASTER_TCP_IP   = '127.0.0.1'
MASTER_TCP_PORT = 11345

NODE_TCP_IP     = '127.0.0.1'
NODE_TCP_PORT   = 11451

TCP_BUFFER_SIZE = 40960


# Listen for Subscribers
s_sub = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sub.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s_sub.bind((NODE_TCP_IP, NODE_TCP_PORT))
s_sub.listen(5)


# Register as a Publisher with Gazebo
pk            = Packet()
pk.stamp.sec  = int(time.time())
pk.stamp.nsec = datetime.now().microsecond
pk.type       = "advertise"

pub           = Publish()
pub.topic     = "/gazebo/default/Pioneer3AT/cmd_vel"
pub.msg_type  = Pose.DESCRIPTOR.full_name
pub.host      = NODE_TCP_IP
pub.port      = NODE_TCP_PORT

pk.serialized_data = pub.SerializeToString()

s_reg = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_reg.connect((MASTER_TCP_IP, MASTER_TCP_PORT))
s_reg.send(hex(pk.ByteSize()).rjust(8))
s_reg.send(pk.SerializeToString())


# Respond to a subscriber
try:
  conn, address = s_sub.accept()
  data = conn.recv(TCP_BUFFER_SIZE)
  
  # Decode Incomming Packet
  pk_sub = Packet()
  pk_sub.ParseFromString(data[8:])
  print "Packet:\n", pk_sub
  
  # Decode Subscription Request
  sub = Subscribe()
  sub.ParseFromString(pk_sub.serialized_data)
  print "Sub:\n", sub
  
  # Pack Data for Reply
  cmd_vel = Pose()
  cmd_vel.name = "Pioneer3AT"
  cmd_vel.position.x = 0.1
  cmd_vel.position.y = 0.2
  cmd_vel.position.z = 0.3
  cmd_vel.orientation.x = 1
  cmd_vel.orientation.y = 2
  cmd_vel.orientation.z = 3
  cmd_vel.orientation.w = 4

  # Publish Packet to Subscriber
  while 1:
    pk_pub            = Packet()
    pk_pub.stamp.sec  = int(time.time())
    pk_pub.stamp.nsec = datetime.now().microsecond
    pk_pub.type       = Pose.DESCRIPTOR.full_name
    pk_pub.serialized_data = cmd_vel.SerializeToString()

    conn.send(hex(cmd_vel.ByteSize()).rjust(8))
    conn.send(cmd_vel.SerializeToString())
    
    time.sleep(0.2)
    
finally:
  #This connection must remain open
  s_reg.close()
```

---

Originally posted by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) with karma: 86 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0